# Linear Paul Trap and Mathieu Equation parameter

Tags: electromagnetism, ion-traps

In the classical linear Paul trap, there are four rods with time-varying potentials that are equal to $\pm V_0 \cos (\Omega t)$ forming an effective quadrupole. If the trapped ion has charge $e$ and mass $M$, the equation of motion that results from the second-order approximated potential from the rods is

$$ M \frac{d^2 u}{dt^2} = \mp \frac{2eV_0}{a^2} \cos (\Omega t)u, $$

where $u(t)$ can be either $x(t)$ (minus sign) or $y(t)$ (plus sign) and $a$ is the distance from the origin to the center of either of the 4 rods. Introducing the dimensionless parameter $q = 4eV_0/ M \Omega a^2$, this equation becomes

$$ \frac{d^2 u}{dt^2} = \mp q \frac{\Omega^2}{2} \cos (\Omega t)u.$$

This is the Mathieu equation for the radial motion of the ion. It can be shown that the total motion is divided into a slow harmonic motion and a fast micromotion around the origin. The approximate solution can be written as follows

$$ u(t) = A \cos \left( \frac{q\Omega}{2\sqrt{2}} t\right)\left[ 1 \pm \frac{q}{2} \cos (\Omega t)\right]. $$

As long as $q<1$, the first factor is associated with the slow motion and the second factor is associated with the fast micromotion. I can see mathematically why that is the case because it implies that the first factor has a frequency that is a fraction of $\Omega$. However, I would like to have a physical interpretation of this. The parameter $q$ looks like the ratio between two potential energies, one of which is electric $(4eV_0)$ and another one which seems to be twice the energy of a harmonic oscillator $(M\Omega^2 a^2)$. If $q<1$, it means that the harmonic potential energy is greater than the electrical potential energy. I can't see the meaning of these potential energies and why that ratio would result in a motion as described above.